# Javascript add/remove class in array only works once

Tags: javascript, dom

I get an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined, where undefined is an array, after I perform a function that add/removes a class to an object in that array.

The code:

```js
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("et_pb_tab");
var toggles = document.getElementById("tabsacc").getElementsByClassName("et_pb_toggle");
for (var i = 0; i < toggles.length; i++) {
  toggles[i].onclick = function() {
    var active = document.querySelector(".et_pb_active_content");
    active.classList.remove("et_pb_active_content", "et-pb-active-slide");
    var num = this.className.slice(-1);
    tabs[num].classList.add("et_pb_active_content", "et-pb-active-slide");
  };
}
```

I am basically trying to combine an accordion and tabs on a site that I'm still getting familiar with. The jQuery library is too old to use some current functions and I haven't updated it yet.

Site is: http://www.aberdeenservices.com/ci-data-tabs

Comment: You are not accessing `value` anywhere in your code.

Comment: You get element by class then remove that class and want to work with that element. Get it by id.

Comment: Isn't `this.className` a string? So `.slice(-1)` returns its last character? Is that intended?

Comment: @Siguza Looks like he expects `className` to be a class that ends with the tab number, so he uses that as an index into `tabs`.

Comment: The problem is that the class that ends with the tab number isn't at the end of `this.className`. When the error occurs, `this.className` is `"et_pb_module et_pb_toggle  et_pb_accordion_item_0 et_pb_toggle_close"`, so it sets `num` to `e` instead of `0`.

Comment: Oh, Barmar you are right, I didn't see that. Thanks for all your responses, this is my first post btw and really appreciate all your input. @Siguza yes I was expecting the last class to have the same number that corresponded with a tab ID. I will have to find another way to get that specific class. Let me investigate and I will post my solution. I am still a rookie at js, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I wrote the code to find the last character of a string of classes, but the tabs module rearranged the order and caused an error. I instead used "search()" to find the index of the class I wanted, added the length, and used "charAt()" to get the number at the end of the class. Thanks guys, the finished code will be at the links below and I've attached my code snippet.

```js
<script>
    var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("et_pb_tab");
    var toggles = document.getElementById("tabsacc").getElementsByClassName("et_pb_toggle");
    for (var i = 0; i < toggles.length; i++) {
        toggles[i].onclick = function() {
            var active = document.querySelector(".et_pb_active_content");
            active.classList.remove("et_pb_active_content","et-pb-active-slide");
            var thisclass = this.className;
            var substrclass = thisclass.search("et_pb_accordion_item_");
            var num = thisclass.charAt(substrclass + 21);
            tabs[num].classList.add("et_pb_active_content","et-pb-active-slide");
        };
    }
</script>
```

http://www.aberdeenservices.com/ci-data-tabs
http://www.aberdeenservices.com/ci-data